# how to extend bash history in Linux Mint 13?

Tags: bash, command-line

How do I increase the command history size in Linux Mint 13?

There is no ~./bash_profile in Linux Mint 13

and changing

```
~/.profile
```

to include something like

```
HISTSIZE=4050
HISTFILESIZE=4050
```

Did not increase history size either.

Please advise.

Dennis

Comment: If `.bash_profile` doesn't already exist, just create it.

Answer (score 6):

Try in your .profile-:

```
export HISTSIZE=4050
export HISTFILESIZE=4050
```

`export` passes the variables to all sub-shells - which are called when commands are issued from the login shell.

Comment: I agree with @suspectus. You should add export. Additionally, you can type echo $HISTSIZE or echo $HISTFILESIZE to find out if variable values were applied.